# Delete Thumbnails Button Created as Joomla Custom Form Field Throws Me Out

Tags: module, custom-field, custom-module, joomla-4.x, images

I am developing a Joomla 4 Content Slider Module and it creates thumbnails in the mysite.com/cache/mymodule/ folder. I am trying to add a delete-thumbnails button. I am using a custom form field for the first time following this tutorial (https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type).

I have created a modules/mod_mymodule/admin/fields/cache.php in my module and added it to the xml file like this:

```
<fieldset name="advanced" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_mymodule/admin/fields/">
    <field name="delete_thumbs" type="Cache" label="Delete Cached Thumbnails" description="Delete Cached Thumbnails"   />
```

Then I have added the button and everything seems okay, but while creating the delete button, I have used 2 different input types. First added a form and input, then added another one without deleting first one. It is weird, but now when I deleted first submit button and tried to use the second delete button it throws me out of module settings. When both of them are there everything is okay. What am I missing?

One more question: Might that way (using unlink command) cause a vulnerability?

Here is my cache.php. As you see at the bottom there are 2 forms to submit button. When I remove the firs one (<form id="formGoBack"), the second form button throws me out when clicked. I have hidden the first one as a solution.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

if(isset($_POST['delete']) && !empty($_POST['delete'])){
    //find the file
    $folder_path = JPATH_SITE .'/cache/mod_jt_contentslider';
   
    // List of name of files inside
    // specified folder
    $files = glob($folder_path.'/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

    foreach ( $files as  $file){
        if(is_file($file)) 
        {
            // Delete the given file
            unlink($file); 
        }
    }
}

class JFormFieldCache extends JFormField {
    protected $type = 'Cache';
    // getLabel() left out
    public function getInput() {
        return '
<form id="formGoBack" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="formGoBack" class="btn btn-primary" ></input>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="delete" name="delete" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Images" /></input>
</form>';
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, please know that `isset($_POST['delete']) && !empty($_POST['delete'])` is a common antipattern. [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403)

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa.

Comment: This is a terrible approach. It's not the field's responsibility to perform actions like deleting files. Consider using `com_ajax` instead https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Sharky